# Difference between ANOVA with two between subjects factors and ANCOVA

Tags: anova, covariance, ancova

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me the difference between an ANOVA with two between subejcts factors (1) and an ANCOVA with one between subjects factor and another between subjects factor as a covariate (2)?

Bascially, when running 1, I get a significant main effect of both Gender and Group (but no interaction between the two).

However when running 2, there is not a significant affect of Group (or Gender if I do it the other way around).

Also when conducting analyses as t-tests separately (3) there is no difference in the dependent variable for either Group or Gender.

Therefore I am confused as to how the different methods account for different sources of variance and why that result in significant affects in 1 but not in 2 or 3.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to have to clarify this. When you say use the factor as a covariate what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Hi mdewey (i'm the original person who posted the question but this website has now linked to my stack exhange so theres a different user name), thanks for responding. What I mean is in the ANOVA i used both Group and Gender as between subjects factors (i.e. i put them both in the between subjects factors box of ANOVA on SPSS); while for the ANCOVA I put group in the between subjects factors box and Gender in the covariate box. Does that make things clearer? thanks again

Comment: @JAir, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to combine your accounts: that will enable you to comment on and edit your post.

Comment: And please do not just post the same question again @JAir without the comments

Comment: Hi, sorry about that- very new to these websites and didn't know what else to do. Does the above make things any clearer? thanks